# Custom Extension Method in LINQ to Objects to return anonymous objects with comparer

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I read that when projecting a new anonymous object from a LINQ to Objects query, the projected object will override its `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods so that executing any further methods that check for equality will work properly.

This made me think that implementing a custom operator that would project an anonymous version of passed in `T` could be useful to avoid overriding these methods in some of my classes or creating custom IComparers.

I would like to use it like this:

```
var newList = list.SelectWithComparer(s => new { s }).Union(List2);
```

Firstly, Is this a good idea?

Secondly, Is it possible?

I have tried the following but can't get the code to compile:

```
public static class LINQExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectWithComparer<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source.Select(s => new { s });          
    }
}
```

The compilation error is due to the anynomous type no longer being of the original T:

```
Error   5   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous types correctly override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods, but the implementation of these methods relies, in turn, on `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods implemented for the types of the properties defined for this object.

So, for instance if you define an object like this:

```
var anonym = new {A = 42, B = "XYZ"};
```

the implementation of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of this anonymous object will call `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of the type `int` (since property `A` is of type `int`) and the type `string` (since property `B` is of type `string`).

That being said, what you want to implement is basically useless. In fact, if you define an anonymous type having a property set to the object `s` e.g. :

```
var myAnonym = new { s };
```

to correctly work as key in dictionaries/hash-tables, `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods of object `s` have to be correctly defined.
But if they are, what's the point in wrapping the object inside an anonymous class ? You can already use it in dictionaries :-)

Comment: Thanks.  I see, I've misunderstood.  I thought the compiler generated a default version of the override of Equals and GetHashCode.  If we still need to manually do this in our classes, what I'm asking is quite useless :)